# Assign Xsl Value from querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, xslt

How can i assign value from querystring.

```
 <xsl:param name="EntityName"><xsl:value-of select="/root/Runtime/EntityName" /></xsl:param>

       <xsl:param name="FilterRk"><xsl:value-of select="/root/Runtime/EntityName" /></xsl:param>
```

First code is working but second one is not working

What can i  do for this situtation?

Answer (score 0):

XSLT cannot directly talk to the query string, since it is not conscious of the URL on which it is running. Any parameters must be explicitly fed into it.

How this is done depends on your environment. In your case, C#/ASP. In PHP, for example, this is achieved via [`XSLTProcessor::setParameter()`](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.xsl-xsltprocessor-set-parameter.htm). Note your XSL must be prepared to receive the variable.

Incidentally, with your current code, there is no need for the `value-of` inside `xsl:param`, you can just use `xsl:param`'s `select` attribute:

```
<xsl:param name='EntityName' select='/root/Runtime/EntityName' />
```

Comment: Thanks your advice.
Now i want to sent this value sql parameter for query.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I have answered the original question. Accept the answer *if* it solves your original problem. If you have a separate question please post it separately.